# Is there !< and !> in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, operators, relational

Someone told me that there's !< and !> in JavaScript. I tried it but it didn't work. Is there something like this in JavaScript? If not in JavaScript, is it there in any other language?

Comment: Short Answer: **NO**, you need to write it as `(!(something > something))` and vice-versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. In JavaScript and many other languages (for numbers - not NaN - and strings):

"!<" is `>=`

"!>" is `<=`

Check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Comment: Not all values are transitive to `>` and `<=`: `NaN > 5 // false`, `NaN <= 5 // false`. So technically `not >` is not `<=` in js typesystem.

Comment: That's true. I edited my answer to clarify that is for numbers and strings only  (which probable is his case)

Comment: `NaN` is a number.

Comment: Well, technically... okay, added a clarification wrt this =p

Comment: Thank you all for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

No `!< and !>` are not there in javascript and in most of the other  programming languages too. You can try > instead of !< and < instead of !>